# UIPopover on ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, uipopovercontroller

I am using ARC on an iPad app with the code below, the popover flashes on the screen, but doesn't stay.
What I am doing wrong?
Please help

```
- (IBAction)photoLibraryAction:(id)sender

{   

   UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   [imagePicker setDelegate:self];

   UIPopoverController *pop1 = [[UIPopoverController alloc]     initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
    [pop1 setDelegate:self];
    [pop1 presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    [pop1 setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 400)];
}


    if  ([pop1 isPopoverVisible])
    {
        // Popover is not visible
        [pop1 dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In ARC, `pop1` will be released right after `-photoLibraryAction:` returns, because ARC doesn't know that `-presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:` makes the object usable beyond its scope.
You'll have to add an instance variable for your popover controller so ARC doesn't release it. Your if-statement is invalid, too, because when the method returns, `pop1` is no longer available for you to use. You'll have to use an instance variable there as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,makes total sense. I will try soon, meanwhile I am avoiding Popover x  ARC and works fine.